# Vertical scroll wheel not working on logitech mx master

Tags: mouse

My vertical wheel does nothing in cases where I expect it to scroll, like in a web browser.  It might have something to do with the fact I ran this command to disable my middle click:

`xmodmap -e "pointer = 1 25 3 4 5 6 7 8 9"`

However, I only want to disable middle click when I use the touchpad.  So I re-enabled middle click:

`xmodmap -e "pointer = 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9"`

Even so, vertical scroll is not working.  It should just [work](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Logitech_MX_Master).  This mouse works fine on Mac.

Answer (score 1):

Restarting the laptop fixed the issue.